# Configure your Outlook add-in for event-based activation on web

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an Office Addin for Outlook and I want to handle the event `OnNewMessageCompose` to call my api and generate a signature from it. I have been able to do it with the Desktop version, but when I try it on web, I am getting the following error in commands.html:
`GET https://localhost:3000/launchevent/launchevent.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

This is the code from commands.html:

```
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT License. -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

    <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../launchevent/launchevent.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
<script src="commands.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

And this is the Manifest used for the Addin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>ID</Id>
  <Version>VERSION</Version>
  <ProviderName>NAME</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Brand Center - DEV2"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Brand Center - DEV2"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="ICON_URL"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="ICON_URL"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/19%3aa82b6ead90d04f7785604f7534f92bc5%40thread.tacv2/General?groupId=431ffc8a-4c8f-4be8-ae53-c8cc687986be%26tenantId=473672ba-cd07-4371-a2ae-788b4c61840e"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>DOMAIN</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <!-- Event-based activation happens in a lightweight runtime.-->
        <Runtimes>
          <!-- HTML file including reference to or inline JavaScript event handlers.
               This is used by Outlook on the web and Outlook on the new Mac UI preview. -->
          <Runtime resid="WebViewRuntime.Url">
            <!-- JavaScript file containing event handlers. This is used by Outlook Desktop. -->
            <Override type="javascript" resid="JSRuntime.Url"/>
          </Runtime>
        </Runtimes>
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgComposeCmdGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeInsertGist">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

          <!-- Can configure other command surface extension points for add-in command support. -->

          <!-- Enable launching the add-in on the included events. -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">
            <LaunchEvents>
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnNewMessageCompose" FunctionName="onMessageComposeHandler"/>
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnNewAppointmentOrganizer" FunctionName="onAppointmentComposeHandler"/>
            </LaunchEvents>
            <!-- Identifies the runtime to be used (also referenced by the Runtime element). -->
            <SourceLocation resid="WebViewRuntime.Url"/>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="IMAGE_URL"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="IMAGE_URL"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="IMAGE_URL"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
        <bt:Url id="WebViewRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
        <!-- Entry needed for Outlook Desktop. -->
        <bt:Url id="JSRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/launchevent.js" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="LABEL"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Brand Center - Localhost"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Title" DefaultValue="Brand Center - Localhost"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    <WebApplicationInfo>
        <Id>ID</Id>
        <Resource>api://localhost:3000/ID</Resource>
        <Scopes>
          <Scope>openid</Scope>
          <Scope>user.read</Scope>
          <Scope>files.read</Scope>
          <Scope>profile</Scope>
        </Scopes>
      </WebApplicationInfo> 
  </VersionOverrides>
</VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

And finally this is my webpack.config.js:

```
const devCerts = require("office-addin-dev-certs");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');

const urlDev="https://localhost:3000/";
const urlProd="PRODUCTION_URL"; // CHANGE THIS TO YOUR PRODUCTION DEPLOYMENT LOCATION

module.exports = async (env, options)  => {
  const dev = options.mode === "development";
  const buildType = dev ? "dev" : "prod";
  const config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      vendor: [
        'react',
        'react-dom',
        'core-js',
        'office-ui-fabric-react'
    ],
    taskpane: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        './src/taskpane/index.tsx',
    ],
    commands: './src/commands/commands.ts'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          use: [
              'react-hot-loader/webpack',
              'ts-loader'
          ],
          exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]',          
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
          use: [
            'file-loader',
          ],
        },
      ]
    },    
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
        {
          from: "./src/launchevent/launchevent.js",
          to: "launchevent.js",
        },
        {
          to: "taskpane.css",
          from: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.css"
        },
        {
          to: "[name]." + buildType + ".[ext]",
          from: "manifest*.xml",
          transform(content) {
            if (dev) {
              return content;
            } else {
              return content.toString().replace(new RegExp(urlDev, "g"), urlProd);
            }
          }
        }
      ]}),
      new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "taskpane.html",
        template: './src/taskpane/taskpane.html',
        chunks: ['taskpane', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "commands.html",
        template: "./src/commands/commands.html",
        chunks: ["commands"]
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Promise: ["es6-promise", "Promise"]
      })
    ],
    devServer: {
      hot: true,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },      
      https: (options.https !== undefined) ? options.https : await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions(),
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000
    }
  };

  return config;
};
```

Comment: We are tracking the event based activation failure in Outlook web at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3241. Please refer to github for further updates.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks correct. You may double check that by going through the guide [Configure your Outlook add-in for event-based activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest).

Sounds like an issue on the JavaScript API for Office (`OfficeJS`) side. I've have just posted a similar issue at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3241.

Comment: But in your case, the based-event works for desktop?

Comment: Correct. Sounds like your case according to the description.

Comment: okey, so we will have to wait for them to solve?

Comment: Yes, you may track updates on the ticket.

Comment: The issue should be resolved now. Please let us know if you are still able to repro the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a separate command for Web.  Run this command `npm run start:web` if it is configured in package.json else try running this one `office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml web`